# Documenten document extension - backfilling documents

Tags: extension, civicase, document-management

I was testing out the functionality of the [Documenten extension](https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.documents) as it looks promising. (We use CiviCase heavily and are starting to scan some paper files and add them to cases.)

The blog post here: https://civicrm.org/blog/petednz/using-and-improving-the-documents-extension-a-drupal-extension-by-civicoop says that you are able to backfill documents already added to cases prior to enabling the extension by running a script. But it's not clear if that script is part of the extension or you have to create and run the script yourself.

Anyone used the extension and have pointers?

Comment: I'm sure @petednz-fuzion will be along soon to answer. I think for this you could also ping him in town-square chat since it really sounds like a custom script they would have used.

Comment: i checked our records, we do have the script etc. ray pls PM me as it is a bit more effort to pull the bits together and ensure it meets someone elses requirements. (and quote Ref: 14057)